# EXCEL - how to get the value of the first column in a row in which value in another column meets certain criteria?

Tags: excel, formula, vlookup

I have an excel spreadsheet with the following data

----- A-----------------B

1 ----X

2

3----January 2012-----30

4----February 2012----50

5----March 2012------105

6----April 2012--------140

I would like to set a formula in A1 cell that would give me the value of column A of the first row, where column B has a value higher than 100... in my case the value would be March 2012

I know I am supposed to use VLOOKUP function, but I never used it and it is kinda science fiction for me... specially because I need to put a conditional in there

please help

Comment: this is what I got right now, but it is not working:
http://www4.picturepush.com/photo/a/7464262/img/7464262.jpg

Comment: Ok, I needed to confirm the formula with ctrl+shift+enter, now it works

Comment: That version is overkill with 2 x INDEX and 2 x MATCH - this version is sufficient with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER - `=INDEX(A3:A12;MATCH(TRUE;B3:B12>100;0))` or you can throw in an additional INDEX so that the formula can be entered normally `=INDEX(A3:A12;MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(B3:B12>100;0);0))`

Comment: @barryhoudini: so why don't you submit your solution as an answer instaed of a comment, so I can award a winning answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment....

You can use this formula based on your jpeg in comment above

`=INDEX(A3:A12;MATCH(TRUE;B3:B12>100;0))`

confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

or you can throw in an additional INDEX so that the formula can be entered normally, i.e.

`=INDEX(A3:A12;MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(B3:B12>100;0);0))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`=CHOOSE(SUM(MATCH(100,B3:B6)+1),A3,A4,A5,A6,A7)`

Comment: SUM is redundant here but I like the concept. INDEX will cope better than CHOOSE with larger ranges, e.g. matching OP's suggestion you can use `=INDEX(A3:A12;MATCH(100;B3:B12)+1)` - B3:B12 needs to be sorted ascending which i assume is the case if they are cumulative totals.

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't to comfortable with use of Index.